# math difference between 2 key-value objects js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

If I have 2 objects like this:

```
var obj1 = {'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 5, 5]}
var obj2 = {'a': [1, 1, 1], 'b': [2, 2, 2]}
```

How can I obtain a third object like this:

```
obj3 = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [3, 3, 3]} // difference between obj1 and obj2
```

I tried, but with no result:

```js
var obj1 = {'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 5, 5]}
var obj2 = {'a': [1, 1, 1], 'b': [2, 2, 2]}
var obj3 = Object.keys(obj1).filter(k => obj1[k] - obj2[k]);
console.log(obj3)
```

Comment: Look at Lodash difference function https://lodash.com/docs#difference

Comment: @Liam it's not the same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** and **[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** methods call to iterate over the `keys` and do the required calculations.

This is how should be your code:

```
var res = {};
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(k){
   res[k] = obj1[k].map((v,i) => v - obj2[k][i]);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var obj1 = {'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 5, 5]}
var obj2 = {'a': [1, 1, 1], 'b': [2, 2, 2]}
var res = {};
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(k){
   res[k] = obj1[k].map((v,i) => v - obj2[k][i]);
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Not actually a need for forEach of the keys, when for..in will work just as well without accessing another object than the one given

Comment: @mplungjan Yes you are right about that, but they are two ways of doing things, thanks  for pointing it out anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

An example using reduce and map.

EDIT: I documented some steps to help you understand what's happening.

```js
/**
 * Returns the difference between each value in an array
 * positioned at each key listed in keys between objA and objB.
 *
 * @param {Object} objA - Every key should container an array of numbers to diff.
 * @param {Object} objB - Should match structure with objA.
 * @param {string[]} [keys] - Optional array with keys to diff, by default uses all the keys.
 * @returns {Object} - Object matching objA structure with diff'ed values in each key.
 */ 
function keyDiff(objA, objB, keys=Object.keys(objA)) {

  // Array.reduce "reduces" an array to a single object using using a function.
  // Function receives 2 arguments:
  // - Accumelated value (val, result of previous steps in every iteration).
  // - Current iterated value of array (key).
  return keys.reduce(function(acc, key) {
    
    // Array.map "maps" one array to another using a function.
    // Function receives 2 arguments:
    // - Current iterated value of array (v).
    // - Current iterator index (index).
    //
    // Current reducer value "key" is used to map objA values for key to
    // differnce with objB. This is done at the position specied by map index.
    // The result is set to the accumulater "acc" object which gets returned
    // at the end of the reducer.
    acc[key] = objA[key].map(function(v, index) {
      // Subtract objB value from objA value
      return v - objB[key][index];
    })
  
    // Return the new accumelator "acc" value.
    // The returned value of each step in the reducer is accumulator "acc".
    // This is the first value in the function passed as argument in the reducer.
    return acc;

  // By Default "null" is the inital accumulator value.
  // Since we need an object to start with we specify "{}" as the inital value.
  }, {});
}

var obj1 = {'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 5, 5]}
var obj2 = {'a': [1, 1, 1], 'b': [2, 2, 2]}

var obj3 = keyDiff(obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj3);
```

Comment: I do not understand the choice of reduce when there is a one to one number of results

Comment: The expected result should be an object, not an array. If the input is an array and the output is an array use `Array.map`. If the input is an array and the output is a primitive or (non-iterable) object use `Array.reduce`.

Comment: Right - missed that one

Comment: Mine is still way easier to grasp in my opinion. Saving the creation of obj3 first is outweighed by the lack of readability https://stackoverflow.com/a/55264605/295783 - still voted up

Comment: Arguably yes, But being correct outweighs readable IMO. Especially when answering a question. Also, this example is a bit verbose in order to be es5 compatible and documented. It can probably be a one liner.

Comment: I certainly did after you made me realise my solution was not actually correct :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest version I could create.

```js
const obj1 = { 'a': [2, 3, 4],'b': [5, 5, 5]};
const obj2 = { 'a': [1, 1, 1],'b': [2, 2, 2]};
let   obj3 = {};

for (k in obj1) {
   obj3[k] = obj1[k].map((v, i) => v - obj2[k][i])
};
console.log(obj3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach which works for any depth objects.

```js
function delta(a, b) {
    return typeof a === 'object'
        ? Object.assign(
            Array.isArray(a) ? [] : {},
            ...Object.keys(a).map(k => ({ [k]: delta(a[k], b[k]) }))
        )
        : a - b;
}

var obj1 = { a: [2, 3, 4], b: [5, 5, 5] },
    obj2 = { a: [1, 1, 1], b: [2, 2, 2] },
    result = delta(obj1, obj2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
var obj1 = {'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 5, 5]}
var obj2 = {'a': [1, 1, 1], 'b': [2, 2, 2]}

var resultObj = {};

for(var i in obj1) {
  var firstObjArray = obj1[i];
  var secondObjArray = obj2[i];
  var differenceArray = firstObjArray.map(function(a, index) {
    return firstObjArray[index] - secondObjArray[index]
  });
  resultObj[i] = differenceArray;
}

console.log(resultObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a reusable array subtraction function.

After that, it'd be a matter of simply looping through the object keys and performing that function on the matching keys.

```js
var obj1 = {'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 5, 5]}
var obj2 = {'a': [1, 1, 1], 'b': [2, 2, 2]}

const subtractArrays = (arr1,arr2) => arr1.map((val,idx) => val-arr2[idx]);

const result = Object.keys(obj1).reduce((out,key) => {
    out[key] = subtractArrays(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
    return out;
  }, {});
  
console.log(result);
```